# Task object did not displaying salesforce

Tags: administration, salesforce1-app, mobile, app-development

I have installed the salesforce 1 mobile application in my ipad. then  go to an opportunity and click on the "+", there are a number of options, but "Tasks" not available kindly sugget.[image]

in mobile application not only single object all are objects.

Thanks 
Hanu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be available there. But if it is not then in this case you can check it on Opportunity page layout which assigned to current logged in user. And check if task is on layout or not.

[image: Opportunity Task Action]